# Allowing Multiple Duplicate Permalinks for Specific ACF-created Post Type

Tags: wordpress, web, anchor, advanced-custom-fields, permalinks

I hope you're doing well. The title pretty much captures what I'm grappling with at the moment. Here's the scenario: I'm working with a post type designed solely for searchable posts using custom fields. The twist is that these posts have permalinks structured like "websiteurl.com/example/example2", followed by a distinctive "#" identifier. This "#" is intended to function as an anchor, directing users to various sections on a single page. This means that several posts end up sharing the same "#" link.

I've taken a dive into various discussions, but unfortunately, I haven't stumbled upon a solution that fits my specific case. I have to admit, I'm fairly new to the world of WordPress, and I might not have a handle on all the intricacies just yet. If this question comes across as a bit off the mark, don't hesitate to point me in the right direction. Your guidance would be immensely appreciated!